# How do people implement "medium" difficulty in NIM games?

Tags: game-theory

NIM is a game where you have several rows of sticks (beads, tokens, etc) and each player takes an arbitrary number of sticks from a single row each turn. In this game, there are no "okay" moves. It's either perfect, or it's a mistake equivalent to random guessing.

So my question is how do people implement a medium difficulty AI in these types of games? Easy difficulty is random guessing, and hard difficulty is perfect play, but what's the intermediate?

Comment: knowing nothing of NIM, what if it chose the best answer 90% of the time, and the wrong answer 10% of the time?

Answer (score 1):

It is inherently hard to implement difficulty into the AI for complete-information solved games like nim. This is because, as you say, any AI that makes a mistake will lose every time to an AI that plays perfectly. Thus there are two "tiers" of gameplay: perfect play, and imperfect play, and games between a perfect and imperfect players will never be interesting.

However, if the goal is to provide a challenge for a human player who does not know the solution to nim, you can improve the AI heuristics in a way similar to how a child or other student might learn to play the game, without fully solving it. A few ideas might be:

- Take an immediate win if it exists (i.e., the last remaining pile in normal nim, or all but one in misère nim)
- When there are two equal piles, reflect the opponent's move on the other pile.
- Never play a move that results in a situation where the opponent can immediately win.
- Do a minimax search up to depth k of possible moves, and evaluate the unclear leaf positions with heuristics like number of equal piles?

These would pose a greater and greater challenge to a good human player who has not seen the solution to execute perfect play.